# CX view of C++ classes

Tags: windows-runtime, c++-cx

I'm writing a program that has a portable C++ backend that we want to create a WinRT Xaml frontend for. I want to keep our models in pure C++ code and create a view in C++/CX that mirrors the C++ model that we can pass around and consume on the frontend. Is there any standard method for this?

For example:

```
class Person
{
public:
    const std::wstring GetName() const;
    void SetName(const std::wstring& value);
private:
    std::wstring m_Name;
}

ref class PersonMirror : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
public:
    property Platform::String^ Name
    {
        Platform::String^ get();
        void set(Platform::String^ value);
    }
private:
    std::shared_ptr<Person> m_Person;
}
```

Some things I don't know how to do in this are:

- How I get the associated ref mirror class from the native class. can I convert a void* to a PersonMirror^ and talk to the GC about holding a reference to the object?
- Are there C++ implementations for triggering events? Or I guess if I can maintain that this is a 1-to-1 relationship, I can just use a function pointer perhaps?

Comment: do you really need to create a CX wrapper for every C++ class you have?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot simply convert a void* to a PersonMirror^. You have to use "ref new" to create a WinRT instance of the class and then copy the data (or a pointer to it) from Person into the PersonMirror. You can have a PersonMirror constructor that copies individual fields from the ISO C++ class, or you can just copy a shared_ptr as you have done, and provide public accessors for it in your ref class. This is a nice approach. Note: There is no "GC" in C++/CX; a ref class is basically just a smart pointer.

• You can use whatever eventing mechanism you like between a ref class and an ISO C++ class in the same process. The only restriction is that any public types in the ref class must be WinRT compatible. To expose a callback or function object event handler in PersonMirror, give it internal accessibilty so that it is invisible to the WinRT interface, but your ISO code can still access it.

The [Reversi](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj712230.aspx) sample on MSDN demonstrates an ISO C++ class that is wrapped by a C++/CX wrapper class.